# how to classify landscape and horizontal images using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have set of images rotated in landscape and upside down. I want to make all images portrait (Vertical). I am using python and openCV library.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet couldn't find a way to start ahead with this

Comment: What about googling it? Just one of the many resources on this topics: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: This requires ground truth to be compared with i don't have that my images are not in uniform manner even the documents are not straight.

Comment: Ok, I think got it. Can you post sample images and the desired results?

Comment: This is the desired ouput http://i.imgur.com/tnehgaD.jpg and http://i.imgur.com/6Csu3i7.jpg , http://i.imgur.com/2BGuRUV.jpg kind of images i have rotated in all degrees.

Comment: Do you want to classify one type of papersheet (i.e. same header and footer) or do you have multiple types to classify?

Comment: I just have to bring the landscape and flipped images back to straight portrait mode yes there are multiple headers and footers  with different shapes and sizes , some files don't have header or footer

Comment: In order to automatically flip papersheets in portrait mode, your algorithm will need some kind of hints. One possibility is to take the template version of your papersheet (in other words, an empty document with just the header/footer. This of course implies that you will only be able to classify papersheets that have a header/footer) and find keypoints using _SIFT_ or _SURF_ methods. Then similarly, find the keypoints of your input image and try to match them with the keypoints of your template. Finally, a function like `findHomography` will give you the transformation of your input image.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try